# Group by - do not Group NULL and control record displayed

Tags: mysql

Similar to this question: [group by not-null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987808/group-by-not-null-values)
I'm trying to only group my records that have the column `groupID` not null:

```
+--+-------+------+-----+-----+----------+
|id|groupId|isMain|name |stars|created   |
+--+-------+------+-----+-----+----------+
..1..abcd....1.....john....5...2018-06-01.
..2..NULL....0.....albert..3...2018-05-01.
..3..abcd....0.....clara...1...2018-06-01.
..4..NULL....0.....steph...2...2018-07-01.
```

With this query I'm able to group only those records where `groupId` is not null:

```
SELECT *, SUM(stars) as stars 
FROM table AS 
GROUP BY (case when `groupId` is null then id else `group` end)
ORDER BY created DESC
```

This gives me the result:

```
4..NULL....0.....steph...2...2018-07-01
3..NULL....0.....clara...6...2018-06-01
2..NULL....0.....albert..3...2018-05-01
```

I'm trying to select, for those records grouped, the ones that `isMain` is `1` but I have no clue how to achieve that.
I've tried playing with `HAVING` but that gives me a totally different result.

Comment: Can you simply omit the rows that have `null` as their `groupId`? I.e. `WHERE groupId IS NOT NULL`. Also, should `else group end` be `else groupId end`?

Comment: No, I also want the records where `groupId` is null.

Comment: Your grouping is incomplete (invalid in most other SQL implementations, and not allowed under recent MySQL default configurations). For groupId `abcd` IsMain in the query results could end up being 1 or 0; and the value used if not even guaranteed to be consistent from one execution of the query to the next. It would probably be helpful to show the results you actually want.

Comment: That's what exactly I'm trying to achieve @Uueerdo, make it consistent ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CASE or IFNULL 
but you should use proper aggregation function and group by columns clause  eg:

```
 select   ifnull(groupID, id), name,  sum(stars), max(created) as my_create
 from  table
 group by ifnull(groupID, id), name
 order by my_create
```

Comment: in my example I simplified on purpose the table structure (number of columns mainly). Does this mean I need to use the proper aggregation function for each column I select?

Comment: or you add  anngregation function for the column not mentioned in group by  .. or you must add  the column name in group  . for others need you must buil a join betwwen the aggreated  resunt and the flat rows